# Why when i train my custom detector it didnt give me output?

Tags: python

Why when i train my custom detector it didnt give me output? (https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1x5Z.png)

Comment: Please don't paste images of your code. Instead post your code and error traceback in codeblocks(\`\`\`) as raw text.

Answer (score 1):

Your error was caused by openCV. You need to read the image before using  `imshow.`

and also please check the directory where your image is stored. you can find more information here: [OpenCV NoneType object has no attribute shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39833796/opencv-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-shape)

```
image = cv2.imread('chart.png')
imshow(image)
```

Comment: I wouldn't say _caused_, more so _raised_. The error was _caused_ by the missing `imread()`.

Comment: thank you! but when i try to run the !./darknet detector train data/obj.data cfg/yolov4-obj.cfg yolov4.conv.137 -dont_show -map it wont show the output only this one CUDA-version: 11060 (11060), cuDNN: 8.4.0, CUDNN_HALF=1, GPU count: 1  
 CUDNN_HALF=1 
 OpenCV version: 4.2.0
 Prepare additional network for mAP calculation...